# How to find n decimal of a value?

Tags: python

I'm trying to divide a number to `n decimals`.

For example

```
def find_digit(number, n):
    return pow(number, n)
    # this should return 0.0005

n = 5
number = 4
print(find_digit(number, n))

1024
```

My expected value is `0.0005` and now I'm sure it is not the power of a value but I can not remember how to calculate this.

Answer (score 4):

You should change the logic from `find_digit` *method*.

`0.0005` is equals to `5 / (10 ^ 4)`

```
def find_digit(number, n):
     return number / pow(10, n)
print(find_digit(number, n))
```

Output

```
>> 0.0005
```

Comment: find_digit(1, 5) returns 0.5 instead of 0.0001

Comment: @DonCoder, then `find_digit(4, 5)` must return `0.00004` ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe less pythonic:

```
def find_digit(number, n):
    return number*pow(10, -n)

print (find_digit(number=5, n=4))
```

Output:

```
>>>0.0005
```

Comment: find_digit(1, 5) returns 0.5. What I'm expecting to get is 0.0001